# Desktop ArcGIS Training Sample Manager cannot merge training samples

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, merge, classification

I have done the following procedure which has resulted in a troubling behavior:

I have a Shapefile Feature Class with multiple different areas under specific distinct description field. I need to make a supervised classification and construct a training sample from e.g, 10 samples to 1 class.

By querying I have made as many Feature Classes as there are different descriptions. Then in order not to make 10 polygons for each one, I have extracted them as Shapefiles (X_description.shp) which are fine indeed on the map.

Then I open the Training Sample Manager which allows me to Load Training Samples and I open a Shapefile, delete all but 10 sample ROIs and try to merge them in one class.

And here is the issue : ArcGIS does not respond to "Merge Training Samples" at all.

However when I draw polygons it is just fine.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how to overcome it in order NOT to make hundreds of polygons manually?

An explanatory screenshot of the procedure and the issue:
[image: scrnsht]

Comment: I could be misunderstanding you, but i think you want to be using the dissolve tool not the merge tool.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and trying to help me out ed.hank, however this is not the case I believe. To be more specific, I have to make the classification in order to check whether the descriptions were correct. The training sample assume that has verified description values.

Comment: can you post a couple screenshots of what you are trying to do, i am still having a hard time completely understanding.  thanks!

Comment: @ed.hank I have attached a modified "screenshot" to visualize the issue